# Improper behaviour at around 600ish px width?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Whats going on with [my site](http://omegadesignla.com) at minimized widths and how can I fix it?

### Problem

It looks good on a mobile phone and full screen, but when sizing down, my background image disappears and the top bar seems to be acting weird (with the logo doing crazy stuff) at around 600ish pixels.

### My `@media query` code:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:1024px)
{
  div.large-7.push-5.columns.last{
  height: emCalc(1px);
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width:675 px){ //745 //481
  .top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon a {
    color: $steel;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 33px;
    padding: 0 25px 0 0;
    position: relative;

}
.container{
  /*background: linear-gradient(to bottom, yellow, magenta);*/
  height: 66rem; /*645px*/
  //overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url('/img/losang.jpg');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
.top-bar{
 // overflow: hidden;
}
  .top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon a:after {
    box-shadow: 0 10px 0 1px $steel, 0 16px 0 1px $steel, 0 22px 0 1px $steel;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 0;
    width: 16px;

}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 674px) { //480
//   .title-area { 
//   max-width: 40%; //or whatever you need for your layout. px will work there, too
// }
// .title-area .logo {
//   width: 100%;
//   height: auto;
// }
 #icons .hover1 {
    .iconlinks {
        color:$iconcolor1;
    }
    
}
#icons .hover2 {
    .iconlinks {
        color:$iconcolor2;
    }
    
}
#icons .hover3 {
    .iconlinks {
        color:$iconcolor3;
    }
    
}



.path-container .path-item .circle.circle-right {
  
  right: 90px;
}

.path-container {
    text-align: center;
  }


  .path-container .circle {
    top: 0;
    // right: 0;
    // left: 0;
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 30px !important;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon a {
    color: $steel;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 33px;
    padding: 0 25px 0 0;
    position: relative;
}
    .top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon a:after {
    box-shadow: 0 10px 0 1px $steel, 0 16px 0 1px $steel, 0 22px 0 1px $steel;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 0;
    width: 16px;
}

.top-bar {
    overflow: hidden;

}
.orbit-container{
  height: 12.5rem;
}
.container{
    /*background: linear-gradient(to bottom, yellow, magenta);*/
    height: 66rem; /*645px*/
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url('/img/losang.jpg');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    /*background-color: #ccc;

.container{
    /*background: linear-gradient(to bottom, yellow, magenta);*/
    //height: 65rem; /*645px*/
    // background-color: blue;
}
.servicesminicontainer{
margin-top:emCalc(0px);
}
.serviceimgs{
  margin: emCalc(0px) auto;

}
.servicescontainer{
  /*background: linear-gradient(to bottom, yellow, magenta);*/
  // height:40rem; /*645px*/
  overflow: hidden;
  background: none;
  /*background-image: url('../img/laback.jpg');*/
  background-size: 100%;
  //background-repeat: no-repeat;
  // background-color: rgba(30,144,255, .7)
  //background: linear-gradient(to bottom, $background-color-top, white);
  //background-image: url('../img/losang.jpg');
}

#icons{
  position: relative;
top: initial;
margin-top: 50px
}
.logo{
    width: 50%;
  // position:relative;
  // top:emCalc(-27px);
}
#topbutton{
    position: relative;
top: 2rem;
}
#icons{
    /*position: relative;
    top:6rem;*/
}


   .container1 p, h4{
    color:black;
}
  header{
    margin-top: 0rem;
    background-image: none;
  
        }

      }
```

Comment: Spam? How is this spam? Thanks for the input, you can go away now jerk.

Comment: sorry for the insults but you really need to get off your coding high horse (as do 80% of users here), maybe my explanation wasn't precise enough for an expert coder like yourself but if you actually went to the site and resized the browser like the post suggests you would get a complete and accurate description of the problem, much better than me trying to describe the problem myself.

Comment: @Omegaman next time, flag offensive comments instead of going on a rant on Meta ;)

Comment: @Dominik: Please clean up your comments, thanks

Comment: @Omegaman: Flagging is the proper response, the offensive comment has been removed, and the post has been edited and fixed. Instead of ranting on meta, use the on-site tools to remedy your issues.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure try with the following styles. Hope it will fix the top header issues.

```
@media only screen and(min-width:500px) and (max-width: 600px)
{
.top-bar .name
 {
  height:auto;
 }
.top-bar
 {
  height:5rem;
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input, the top bar is bouncing around and the logo jumps around getting big then going going off screen.